# How to Enable Audio for getusermedia?

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

I Have got most of this working the only thing that does not work is the Audio, the video Records but without Audio how do i enable Audio and it gets Recorded to?

I Did enable Audio but for some reason it still does not work?
Any Help Will be Great.
\

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
<link href="./Record a getUserMedia() Session_files/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<title>Record a getUserMedia() Session</title>
<style>
a[download] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h4 {
  padding: 15px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  border-radius: 100px 0 100px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section > div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  min-width: 400px;
}
#video-preview {
  height: 300px;
}
button.recording {
  color: darkred;
  border-color: red;
}
section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<details>
  <summary>What's this?</summary>
  <div>
    <p>An example of creating a .webm movie from a <code>getUserMedia()</code> video capture.</p>
    <p><b>Support:</b> Chrome 21 supports <code>getUserMedia()</code>.</p>
  </div>
</details>

<h2>Recording .webm video from a <code>getUserMedia()</code>.</h2>

<section>
<div style="float:left;">
  <button id="camera-me">1. Turn on camera</button>
  <h4><code>getUserMedia()</code> feed</h4>
  <video autoplay=""></video>
</div>
<div id="video-preview">
  <button id="record-me" disabled="">2. Record<!--⚫--></button>
  <button id="stop-me" disabled="">◼</button>
  <!--<button id="play-me" disabled>►</button>-->
  <span id="elasped-time"></span>
  <h4>.webm recording</h4>
</div>
</section>

<!--<script src="libwebp-0.1.3.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="./Record a getUserMedia() Session_files/ga.js"></script><script src="./Record a getUserMedia() Session_files/whammy.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(exports) {

exports.URL = exports.URL || exports.webkitURL;

exports.requestAnimationFrame = exports.requestAnimationFrame ||
    exports.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || exports.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    exports.msRequestAnimationFrame || exports.oRequestAnimationFrame;

exports.cancelAnimationFrame = exports.cancelAnimationFrame ||
    exports.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || exports.mozCancelAnimationFrame ||
    exports.msCancelAnimationFrame || exports.oCancelAnimationFrame;

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var ORIGINAL_DOC_TITLE = document.title;
var video = $('video');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); // offscreen canvas.
var rafId = null;
var startTime = null;
var endTime = null;
var frames = [];

function $(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector) || null;
}

function toggleActivateRecordButton() {
  var b = $('#record-me');
  b.textContent = b.disabled ? 'Record' : 'Recording...';
  b.classList.toggle('recording');
  b.disabled = !b.disabled;
}

function turnOnCamera(e) {
  e.target.disabled = true;
  $('#record-me').disabled = false;

  video.controls = false;

  var finishVideoSetup_ = function() {
    // Note: video.onloadedmetadata doesn't fire in Chrome when using getUserMedia so
    // we have to use setTimeout. See crbug.com/110938.
    setTimeout(function() {
      video.width = 320;//video.clientWidth;
      video.height = 240;// video.clientHeight;
      // Canvas is 1/2 for performance. Otherwise, getImageData() readback is
      // awful 100ms+ as 640x480.
      canvas.width = video.width;
      canvas.height = video.height;
    }, 1000);
  };

  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    finishVideoSetup_();
  }, function(e) {
    alert('Fine, you get a movie instead of your beautiful face ;)');

    video.src = 'Chrome_ImF.mp4';
    finishVideoSetup_();
  });
};

function record() {
  var elapsedTime = $('#elasped-time');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height;
  var CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width;

  frames = []; // clear existing frames;
  startTime = Date.now();

  toggleActivateRecordButton();
  $('#stop-me').disabled = false;

  function drawVideoFrame_(time) {
    rafId = requestAnimationFrame(drawVideoFrame_);

    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

    document.title = 'Recording...' + Math.round((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) + 's';

    // Read back canvas as webp.
    //console.time('canvas.dataURL() took');
    var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 1); // image/jpeg is way faster :(
    //console.timeEnd('canvas.dataURL() took');
    frames.push(url);

    // UInt8ClampedArray (for Worker).
    //frames.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT).data);

    // ImageData
    //frames.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
  };

  rafId = requestAnimationFrame(drawVideoFrame_);
};

function stop() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(rafId);
  endTime = Date.now();
  $('#stop-me').disabled = true;
  document.title = ORIGINAL_DOC_TITLE;

  toggleActivateRecordButton();

  console.log('frames captured: ' + frames.length + ' => ' +
              ((endTime - startTime) / 1000) + 's video');

  embedVideoPreview();
};

function embedVideoPreview(opt_url) {
  var url = opt_url || null;
  var video = $('#video-preview video') || null;
  var downloadLink = $('#video-preview a[download]') || null;

  if (!video) {
    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.controls = true;
    video.loop = true;
    //video.style.position = 'absolute';
    //video.style.top = '70px';
    //video.style.left = '10px';
    video.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
    video.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';
    $('#video-preview').appendChild(video);

    downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.download = 'capture.webm';
    downloadLink.textContent = '[ download video ]';
    downloadLink.title = 'Download your .webm video';
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(downloadLink);

    $('#video-preview').appendChild(p);

  } else {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
  }

  // https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy
  // var encoder = new Whammy.Video(1000/60);
  // frames.forEach(function(dataURL, i) {
  //   encoder.add(dataURL);
  // });
  // var webmBlob = encoder.compile();

  if (!url) {
    var webmBlob = Whammy.fromImageArray(frames, 1000 / 60);
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(webmBlob);
  }

  video.src = url;
  downloadLink.href = url;
}

function initEvents() {
  $('#camera-me').addEventListener('click', turnOnCamera);
  $('#record-me').addEventListener('click', record);
  $('#stop-me').addEventListener('click', stop);
}

initEvents();

exports.$ = $;

})(window);

</script>
<script>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22014378-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
<script>CFInstall.check({mode: 'overlay'});</script>
<![endif]-->

</body></html>
```